# Excel: Return a single value based on two references

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two values that a person would enter information for in column B:

```
Spreadsheet Name: Info
      A          B 
1   Level        2
2   Class        Class 2
```

In a second spreadsheet within the Workbook, i have a data spreadsheet with various tables.

So when a person enters information in !InfoB2 data validation drop down, it would return the name of the table the formula should use to search for the value in the Data table that's level is related to !InfoB2.

```
    Spreadsheet Name: Data
    Table Name: Class 1
          A           B
    1    Level       BAB
    2    --------------------
    3    1            8
    4    2            3

    Table Name: Class 2
          A           B
    1    Level       BAB
    2    --------------------
    3    1            2
    4    2            7
```

So when someone enters Level: 2, and Class2, i would like it to return the value in the BAB column, how can i do this?

Edit
As ghetto as this is, it feels like it's on the right track, however it's returning #VALUE!

```
    VLOOKUP(B1,VLOOKUP(B2,Class,2,FALSE),2,FALSE)
```

Table Class

```
    Table Name: Class
           A         B
    1  Class Name    Table Name
    2  Class 1        Class1Table
    3  Class 2        Class2Table
```

Comment: Could you give more information? In what cell are each of the values? What is inputted by a user? Only '2' and 'Class2'? Where (in what cells) do they put that? Do you have multiple sheets? Which ones?

Comment: My apologies for not being clearer, i will edit my post.

Comment: It's okay, we understand that you're still new here and we can't always know what's important information and what's not :) If you can put "A B C ..." for headings and "1 2 3 ..." for the rows, the whole thing becomes lots easier in terms of cells.

Comment: Let me know if that helps. I am familiar with vlookup, so i know i could do a single references, single table lookup, but not a lookup based on two references where it should select the table based on what  reference is being done in !InfoB2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following formula:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(B2&"[#All]"), MATCH(B1,INDIRECT(B2&"[[#All],[Level]]"),0), 2)
```

This takes the value of B2 (`Class2` note I removed the space since table names can't contain spaces) and concatenates it with `[#All]` so you get: `Class2[#All]` (this is the table reference). `INDIRECT` converts the text into a valid range.

`INDIRECT(B2&"[[#All],[Level]]")` similarly gives the range `Class2[[#All],[Level]]`.

`MATCH(B1,Class2[[#All],[Level]],0)` gives the row number in which the value in B1 is found (i.e. gives the row in which `2` is found, meaning the result is `4`)

`=INDEX(Class2[#All], 4, 2)` then returns the value from range `Class2[#All]` in the 4th row and 2nd column.

Comment: The site went down yesterday and couldn't post earlier =/

Comment: Adapted it for my spreadsheet, and it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you will want to use `INDIRECT` and/or the [structured reference syntax](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-HA010155686.aspx) for this one.
I don't have access to Excel at the moment so I can't check to see if this would work.  I'll update this answer once I try some stuff out.

Comment: i've never used indirect before, but i can start reading about it.

Comment: Don't. In general, if you're using indirect, you're doing it wrong. I'll grant that, given how your data is laid out now, indirect might be the most straightforward way to do what you want, but use of indirect is a good indication that you should restructure your data.